# Android CustonView - How implement selectable items for resizing a CustonView in a parent View?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

everyone. I am not very familiar with the Android system and need food for thought or a hint on how best to implement my idea.I would like to create a resizable CustonView. I have already created the basic structure of the CustonView. I can also assign a Drawable.xml to this to make it clear to the user that this CustonView is selected. But this is just a shape. I would like it to look something like the graphic below.

[draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8KFC.png)

Ideally, each element should be independently selectable. In any case, I would be grateful for any hints or even examples.

Comment: I think you need to be a little clearer on what you want.  Do you just want help on drawing little selected icons at each corner?  And what does resizing have to do with that?  Are you asking for help on resizing the view?  Each element should be independently selectable-  what elements?  Each thingy at the corners?  You really need to explain what you want in far more detail.  Likely this is actually multiple questions

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I currently have an idea of ​​how to implement my project. If this idea doesn't work I will clarify my question, otherwise I will present my solution.